# Swiping between questions on android

Tags: bug, android-app

Since the new update, it is impossible on my cell phone to swipe the list of questions to the left. I can swipe right on questions that were previously scrolled over, but I can't go back again.

This is happening in the main question feed, on a Oneplus One

Comment: Same happens on my Nexus 9 and Nexus 5. It worked ok till this update.